# Casting list of lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a beginner Haskell question.

I'm using Advent of Code this year to learn Haskell. Working through the [first problem](https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/1), I need to cast strings to integers.

This is my code:

```hs
import Data.List.Split
import System.IO

main = do
    input <- getContents
    let bags = splitWhen (=="") $ lines input
    let bagsInteger = map (\arr -> map (\x -> read x :: Integer)) bags :: [[Integer]]
    let totals = map (sum) bagsInteger
    putStrLn $ show $ maximum totals
```

When running `ghc`, I get

```
azl@Alains-MacBook-Air aoc-2022 % ghc 1.hs
Loaded package environment from /Users/azl/.ghc/aarch64-darwin-9.2.5/environments/default
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( 1.hs, 1.o )

1.hs:7:36: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type: [Integer]
                  with actual type: [String] -> [Integer]
    • Probable cause: ‘map’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the expression: map (\ x -> read x :: Integer)
      In the first argument of ‘map’, namely
        ‘(\ arr -> map (\ x -> read x :: Integer))’
      In the expression:
          map (\ arr -> map (\ x -> read x :: Integer)) bags :: [[Integer]]
  |
7 |     let bagsInteger = map (\arr -> map (\x -> read x :: Integer)) bags :: [[Integer]]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Since you are learning, I'll offer a few comments. 1) There's no need to parenthesize a single name in Haskell, ever -- `map (sum) list` is best written `map sum list`. 2) The function `\arg -> f arg` is the same as `f`. Consequently, `map (\arr -> map (\x->read x::Integer) arr) bags` is the same as `map (map (\x->read x::Integer)) bags`. 3) `putStrLn $ show $ ...` is so common that it can be shortened to `print $ ...`. 4) I'd recommend you turn warnings on using the `-Wall` flag, since that catches several beginner mistakes. Have a nice Haskelling!

Comment: For unix-style stdin-to-stdout programs, there is also a convenience function `interact`, which makes this program quite concise: `interact (show . maximum . map (sum . map read) . splitWhen null . lines)`. (This uses the defaulting rules to choose `Integer` for the `read`, but if you want to include an explicit type signature that would also be reasonable.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot `arr`!

```
map (\arr -> map (...) arr) bags
--                     ^^^
```